# What is the plural of Easter Bunny?

Tags: irregular-plurals

Is the plural for the Easter Bunny "Easter Bunnies"?  Or because it's a proper name, is it "Easter Bunnys," much like the plural you see written on the welcome mat for a family whose last name is "Landry" is "The Landrys'," not "The Landries'"?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a definitive source for why it should be "Easter Bunnies", but I can't find a rationale that concretely justifies "Easter Bunnys".

But here is something that I do think makes sense.

There is only one Easter Bunny. It is the Easter Bunny. So there is rarely a reason to use the plural form. It could happen, however.

For example, at a costume party, ten people show up dressed as the Easter Bunny. Someone might say, "I took a photo of five of the Easter Bunnies." I can't find a reason why the "Bunnies" form should not be used.

Comment: Thank you! There is only one Easter Bunny. Indeed. There may be figurative or chocolate Easter Bunnies. I saw a row of them the week before last in a supermarket.